# iOS, OpenGL ES presentRenderbuffer with GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENTx, (x is not 0.)

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I am ramping up OpenGL ES3 in iOS platform and have encountered one trivial issue regarding the FBO's attachment point and presentRenderbuffer call.

Basically, unless the renderbuffer is attached to GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, 
"presentRenderbuffer" doesn't work, just blank screen only.
(For instance, if GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1 is used, it doesn't work. Only the "0" attachment point works, presenting the correct rendering results on the screen.) 
I had added glDrawBuffers to assign the destination buffers but it didn't help.

I have searched many documents and Q&As, but nothing mentioned regarding any restrictions against using non-0 color attachment points in FBO to connect to CAEAGLLayer. Though I could see one diagram in the Apple's OpenGL ES programming guide that shows the "0" attachment point in it as an example diagram but I couldn't see any certain statements. Is it normal? Is only the "0" attachment point allowed? Or what did I miss?
I think it must be a trivial one, but unfortunately it has wasted me a couple of days already, so I came here for help. Thanks, in advance.

```
GLuint _frameBuffer;
GLuint _colorRenderBuffer;   

glGenFramebuffers(1, &_frameBuffer);
glGenRenderbuffers(1, &_colorRenderBuffer);

glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, _colorRenderBuffer);
[_context renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER fromDrawable:_eaglLayer];

glFramebufferRenderbuffer( GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 
                           GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, // it is NOT "0" attachment point.    
                           GL_RENDERBUFFER, 
                           _colorRenderBuffer);

// for the sake, I had added this, too, but no help.
GLenum drawBufferList[1] = {GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1};
glDrawBuffers(1, drawBufferList);

//
// ... rendering to FBO
//

// Somehow this doesn't work 
// unless the FBO attachment point is (GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0).
BOOL presentSuccess;
presentSuccess = [_context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER];
```

======================================================
Additional posting

## that includes the shaders and skeleton of renderer, too.

```
// -------------------------------------------------
// Vertex Shader
#version 300 es

in vec4 Position;        // input position vector
in vec4 SourceColor;     // input color
out vec4 DestinationColor;  // output color

// uniform
uniform mat4 Projection;  // projection matrix
uniform mat4 ModelView;   // modelView matrix

in vec2 TexCoordIn;  // texture coordinate. Texture image is a 2D data, so.
out vec2 TexCoordOut;

void main(void) {
    DestinationColor = SourceColor;
    gl_Position =  Projection * ModelView * Position;

    TexCoordOut = TexCoordIn;
}
// -----------------------------------------


// -----------------------------------------
// Fragment Shader
#version 300 es
in lowp vec4 DestinationColor;
in lowp vec2 TexCoordOut;  

uniform sampler2D Texture;     

layout(location = 0) out lowp vec4 colorOutput; // "location(0)"

void main(void) {
    colorOutput = DestinationColor * texture(Texture, TexCoordOut);
}
// ---------------------------------------------------


// ---------------------------------------------------
// skeleton of renderer
//
- (void)render:(CADisplayLink *)displayLink
{
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, _frameBuffer);

    // Even I have tried this, 
    // to map the location(0) in the fragment shader 
    // to the GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1.
    // But it didn't help.
    GLenum drawBufferList[1] = { GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1 };
    glDrawBuffers(1, drawBufferList);


    glClearColor(0, 104.0/255, 55.0/255.0, 1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    //    
    // do rendering...
    //    

    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, _colorRenderBuffer[0]);

    // draw
    // Somehow this doesn't work 
    // unless the FBO attachment point is (GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0).
    BOOL presentSuccess;
    presentSuccess = [_context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER];
}    
// ------------------------------
```

I have updated the post with some results, after having comments from "solidpixel".
Briefly summarizing the results, it is possible to use non-zero attachment points in FBO to attach the renderbuffer whose storage is associated with CAEAGLLayer. But it must be under some constraints that I have mentioned in the code snippet below. Basically, glDrawBuffers doesn't work as it is supposed to be. To be able to use non-zero attachment points for the renderbuffer that has interface to CAEAGLLayer, the fragment shader's output must be set to the "matched" color attachment index. (In another words, (location=0) output in the shader cannot be connected to other than GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0. Furthermore, with "this default-like" mapping, glDrawBuffers still needs to be run with a correct mapping array, to be able to use non-0 color attachments in FBO. 
I still hope that I would had missed something in the configuration. But I cannot help but saying that setting up of the FBO that has CAEAGLLayer interface looks somewhat different to other "typical" FBOs that don't have CAEAGLLayer interface with them. (For additional example, I have mentioned another mystery in the code snippet, that the FBO with CAEAGLLayer interface doesn't look like allowing to have more than one color attachments. Very weird.)

```
// **********************************
// The following code snippet shows the case of how to successfully     
// setup the FBO and renderbuffer with CAEAGLLayer, 
// using non-0 attachment points (GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENTx, x is not '0').
//  
// Somehow, glDrawBuffers doesn't work as it is supposed to be.
// To be able to use non-zero attachment color attachment points in FBO,
// three things must be set accordingly to the same color attachment point.
// (I have marked with "<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<" in the code snippets below.
//
// 1) FBO's attachment point for the renderbuffer that its memory is associated with CAEAGLLayer.
// 2) fragment shader output location index.
// 3) glDrawBuffer's argument array element. 
//    
// So all three must be set to GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1 
// to make presentRenderbuffer correctly with the CAEAGLLayer.
// (For glDrawBuffers's input array must be {GL_NONE, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, GL_NONE}).
//
// This is not what glDrawBuffers is supposed to behave, 
// it is supposed to be able to map the fragment shader's output array to
// any preferred color-attachment points. 
// I still hope that I would had missed somthing, to have this results,
// however upon this results that I have so far, 
// I cannot help but saying the FBO that has interface to CAEAGLLayer is different,
// so it's better to leave it alone, only for the interface to CAEAGLLayer.
//    



// ------------------------------------------------    
// FBO and renderbuffer setup before rendering.
// This FBO has the renderbuffer 
// whose storage is associated with CAEAGLLayer for presentRenderbuffer().
//
GLuint _frameBuffer;
GLuint _colorRenderBuffer;   

glGenFramebuffers(1, &_frameBuffer);
glGenRenderbuffers(1, &_colorRenderBuffer);

glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, _colorRenderBuffer);
[_context renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER fromDrawable:_eaglLayer];

glFramebufferRenderbuffer( GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 
                           GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, // <<<<<<<<<< It is set to the attachment point#1.    
                           GL_RENDERBUFFER, 
                           _colorRenderBuffer);
//
//
// Somehow it is not allowed to have more than one GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENTx renderbuffer attachment 
// to "this FBO" (that has the interface to CAEAGLLayer). Otherwise the FBO completeness check fails.
// (Btw, DepthBuffer attachment (GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT) is ok.
//
// For instance, if I add the following in this FBO setup, then the FBO completeness test fails.
// I don't know why. But it has no problem with other FBOs that don't have the interface to CAEAGLLayer,
// to have multiple renderbuffer attachments.
// Somehow, the FBO with CAEAGLLayer interface is different to other FBOs that do not have CAEAGLLayer interface.
//
// GLint framebufferWidth;
// GLint framebufferHeight;
// glGetRenderbufferParameteriv(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH, &framebufferWidth);
// glGetRenderbufferParameteriv(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RENDERBUFFER_HEIGHT, &framebufferHeight);
//
// GLuint addtionalRenderBuffer;
// glGenRenderbuffers(1, &additionalRenderBuffer);
// glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, additionalRenderBuffer);
// glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RGBA8, _framebufferWidth, _framebufferHeight);
// glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT3, GL_RENDERBUFFER, additionalRenderBuffer);
// glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER,0);
// -------------------------------------------------
//    



// -------------------------------------------------
// Vertex Shader
#version 300 es

in vec4 Position;        // input position vector
in vec4 SourceColor;     // input color
out vec4 DestinationColor;  // output color

// uniform
uniform mat4 Projection;  // projection matrix
uniform mat4 ModelView;   // modelView matrix

in vec2 TexCoordIn;  // texture coordinate. Texture image is a 2D data, so.
out vec2 TexCoordOut;

void main(void) {
DestinationColor = SourceColor;
gl_Position =  Projection * ModelView * Position;

TexCoordOut = TexCoordIn;
}
// -----------------------------------------



// -----------------------------------------
// Fragment Shader
#version 300 es
in lowp vec4 DestinationColor;
in lowp vec2 TexCoordOut;  

uniform sampler2D Texture;     

layout(location = 1) out lowp vec4 colorOutput; // <<<<<<<<<<<<< It must be set to (location = 1).

void main(void) {
    colorOutput = DestinationColor * texture(Texture, TexCoordOut);
}
// ---------------------------------------------------



// ---------------------------------------------------
// skeleton of renderer
//
- (void)render:(CADisplayLink *)displayLink
{
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, _frameBuffer);

    // >>>>>>>>>>>> The glDrawBuffer must mention attachment point#1 correctly.
    GLenum drawBufferList[3] = { GL_NONE, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, GL_NONE }; 
    glDrawBuffers(3, drawBufferList);    // >>>>>>>>>>>> The size of buffer "3" must be entered correctly.




    glClearColor(0, 104.0/255, 55.0/255.0, 1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);


    //    
    // do rendering...
    //    

    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, _colorRenderBuffer);

    // draw
    BOOL presentSuccess;
    presentSuccess = [_context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER];
}    
// ------------------------------
```

Additional update regarding glDrawBuffers.
I had carefully reviewed the glDrawBuffers in the OpenGL ES 3.0 specification and had found the following statements:

void glDrawBuffers( GLsizei n,  const GLenum *bufs);

"GL_INVALID_OPERATION is generated if the GL is bound to a framebuffer object and the ith buffer listed in bufs is anything other than GL_NONE or GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENTSi."

This means, the i-th buffer in the buffer array for the input argument of glDrawBuffers must be either GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT(i) or GL_NONE. 
(i = 0, 1,2,..., GL_MAX_DRAW_BUFFERS)

For example, the 2nd buffer in the buffer array must be 
either "GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1" or "GL_NONE".

Any GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENTx other than (x=1), causes the error code: GL_INVALID_OPERATION.

If GL_NONE is disregarded (for example), then there is only one buffer array can exist:

{ GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT2, ... }

In that way, the functionality of glDrawBuffers is nothing but an on/off switch between the user defined output variables of fragment shader and FBO. Basically, it is not possible to map the fragment shader's output to FBO's color attachment points in any desired ways, because the mapping is already fixed. location-0 => color attachment pt0, location-1 => pt1, etc. The only way to change the color attachment point for the shader's output is to change the location of the output in the shader itself. If it is true, I don't understand what the reason for this function glDrawBuffers. Anyway, if the buffer array is built in this way, with its index as increasing order (0,1,2,3,...) for the color attachment points, the code works. But this is very disappointing and also makes me very confused because it is against the descriptions of glDrawBuffers function in several other books and articles as well. However, no matter what others have mentioned, only the standard specification matters, so I cannot help but accepting this as a fact. 
So returning to the original question how to use non-zero attachment point in FBO for presentRenderbuffer function can be implemented as follows. In this case, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1 is used.

```
//
// fragment shader's output
layout(location = 1) out lowp vec4 colorOutput;


//
// FBO and renderbuffer setup.
GLuint _frameBuffer;
GLuint _colorRenderBuffer;   

glGenFramebuffers(1, &_frameBuffer);
glGenRenderbuffers(1, &_colorRenderBuffer);

glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, _colorRenderBuffer);
[_context renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER fromDrawable:_eaglLayer];

glFramebufferRenderbuffer( GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 
                       GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1,  // non-zero color att-pt. 
                       GL_RENDERBUFFER, 
                       _colorRenderBuffer);



//
// in the renderer, the contents of that renderbuffer is presented.
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, _frameBuffer);

// the attachment pt must be GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, 
// because the shader output location is "1".
GLenum drawBufferList[3] = { GL_NONE, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, GL_NONE }; 
glDrawBuffers(3, drawBufferList);    

//
// do rendering ,,,,
//

glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, _colorRenderBuffer);
BOOL presentSuccess;
presentSuccess = [_context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER];
```

Comment: What is your shader program? You shader will need to be different to cope with the fact you are writing out to a different attachment index.

Comment: Thanks, for your comments. I have updated my posting with shader codes and skeleton of renderer as well. Basically, I have created the renderbuffer whose memory is associated with CAEAGLLayer, and bind that renderbuffer to the GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, (not 0).  (cont'd in the following comment).

Comment: (cont'd)  And in the fragment shader, I have assigned "location 0" for the output and connect it to the GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1 by by using glDrawBuffers at the very beginning of the renderer, right after binding the FBO. I think I have followed very typical textbook approach, with only one difference in the color attachment point, which is "1" not "0". Any suggestion/comments will be much appreciated.

Comment: What you have looks correct to me. If you try setting glDrawBuffers to {GL_NONE, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_1}, and binding the output to location 1 does it work?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I have tested with your suggestion, and could present the rendering results in the renderbuffer that is attached to non-zero attachment point in FBO. However, I don't understand why glDrawBuffers doesn't work as it is supposed to be (as mentioned in many other documents, though they are not for iOS.) I have updated the post. I cannot help but saying setting up FBO with CAEAGLLayer is somewhat different compared to other FBOs.

Comment: Yep, I'm pretty sure what you have should work - it smells like a driver bug in the iOS GLES driver to me. Does it work for "normal" offscreen FBOs?.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.
I have found that there is an error code description of glDrawBuffers in OpenGLES3.0.

"GL_INVALID_OPERATION is generated if the GL is bound to a framebuffer object and the ith buffer listed in bufs is anything other than GL_NONE or GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENTSi." 

Which means i-th element of the array must be either GL_NONE or GL_COLORATTACHMENT(i) only.
i.e. { att-pt0, att-pt1, att-pt2,,}, att-pt(x) is GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT(x) or GL_NOP. So the "mapping array" is fixed by the spec. it doesn't allow any mapping of shader outputs to the FBO att-pts as user desires. (con'd

Comment: (cont'd) If my understanding of this glDrawBuffer's error code description is correct, that is disappointing because glDrawBuffers does not do any user desired mapping at all. I have tested the glDrawBuffers against off-screen FBOs, and it looks same as on-screen FBO's. The mapping array needs to be fixed in an increasing order of attachment points' indices unless any GL_NOP is used. To be able to verify the output of off-screen FBO's rbo, I have used glBlitFramebuffer to move the rendering results to on-screen's. I have updated my posting with further development. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: Ah, good spot. Curiosity - why is it so important that you emit to attachment 1 in location 0? The attachment points and locations are entirely virtual concepts, so it seems possible to moving things around in the application without any performance impact just by remapping the locations (e.g. by padding glDrawBuffer element 0 with a GL_NONE),

Comment: During my ramping up OpenGL ES in iOS, I became aware of that  FBO & renderbuffer must be used to present the rendering results in iOS. With that requirement, I have been trying to import other existing shaders into my design. During this effort, I have tried several different combinations of connecting multiple RBOs and FBOs with that "on-screen FBO", to make the design efficiently. More I tried, more I found the mysteries upon the on-screen FBO (that has the interface to CAEAGLLayer). Then I have started coming across the issues like this one. Thanks for your comments to resolve my inquiry.